# How can i pass a radio button value , to my Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following inside my view inside my Asp.net MVC web application:-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology2.Tag, new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete2", "Switch") })
```

which will call the AutoComplete2 action method, and pass the current values of the TextBoxFor to it. my action method looks as follow:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Switch")]
        public ActionResult AutoComplete2(string term)
        {
            var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term).OrderBy(p => p.Tag).Select(a => new { label = a.Tag }).ToList();
            return Json(tech, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```

now a new requirment have been raised that there should be two radio buttons (Tag & Serial)  to determine if the user need to do an autocomplete using the Tag number of the Serial number. my current field will pass the tag number. so how i can force the Url.Action to reference different action method based based on the radio button selection, or to pass the radio button value and pass it to the same action method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HiddenField to store the value of the Radio button and pass the Hidden Field value through URL action link.

This isn't razor syntax but it obviously still works and you can convert it if you'd like.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Hidden, new { id = "hf" });

<input type="radio" name="rb" value="1" onclick="change()"/>
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="2" onclick="change()"/> 
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="2" onclick="change()"/>
```

Capture the Change event in JQuery and set the Hidden field value.

```
function change() {
    $('input[name="rb"]').click(function () {           
        $("#hf").val(this.value);
    });
}
```

And you should be able to pass it through like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastNamex,
new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete2", "Switch", 
new { id = Model.Hidden }) })
```

Comment: but in my current apprach the  "$('input[name="rb"]').click(function () {" will never fire as the user will not click on any button while typing the auto complete search term ...

Comment: Ok if the user isn't checking off rb's I'm not sure what event does it, but anyhow, on whatever event you are selecting the rb, I would store that value in session. Have the tb call 1 action method, and use session there to determine what lookup to do.

Answer (score -1):

Use conditional operator inside to choose URL.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology2.Tag, new { data_autocomplete_source = $("#radio_1").prop("checked")?Url.Action("AutoComplete2", "Switch"): otherURL })
```